# How do i get this to properly exit the program?

Tags: c

So i am trying to get this program to simply exit but i can seem to get it to work.

i tried a lot of things. one thing i found odd as well is if i made x = 0 in the while loop it would immediately exit the program so i had to make it x !=0. i dont understand what that is so if you can answer that as well that would be nice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a[256];
    int x = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        int y = strcmp(fgets(a, 256, stdin), "exit");
        if (y==0) {
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            printf("Line read:%s\n",a);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so it should output right now something like this(i am also running this in a linux terminal):

```
//input://
 hello
//output:// 
 Line read: hello
//(program stays open for more inputs)//
//input//
 exit
//(the program now closes in the terminal and you return to directory)//
```

Comment: You're declaring a new `x` variable in your `while` condition.  That's not going to work.  `x` is *already declared.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah i just typed it on the website wrong it still exits after i open it

Comment: @user3121023 this worked can you tell me why that is.

Comment: It works better if you just copy/paste your code into Stack Overflow instead of trying to retype it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yeah i would but i have to run this on a vm and my schools internet doesnt work if i have a VM on because it doesnt recognize my pc.

Comment: `fgets` may return NULL in case of read error so this is not a safe usage

Comment: @user3121023 oh okay im new to c so i dont know how to fully use these functions. Anyways thanks for the help. if you want credit for it go ahead and post the answer for it.

Comment: @M.M Yeah i agree but my professor wanted me to use the fgets function

Comment: Just remember that fgets stores EVERY character you type.  It stops AFTER you press Enter but by then it has already stored the Enter character.

Comment: @DamionOwens you should store the return value and check it to be non-null, before doing `strcmp` on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard input contains a new line at the end. Change `"exit"` to `"exit\n"` in call to `strcmp`.